# SilverStripe extensions for GridFieldConfig

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to create a class that simplifies re-building a `GridFieldConfig` each time. I use the following setup for nearly every GridFieldConfig in my CMS:

```
$config = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
      new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
      new GridFieldAddNewButton('toolbar-header-right'),
      new GridFieldTitleHeader(),
      ... etc
    )
```

Rather than repeating myself each time, I'd rather create a class that returns an instance of GridFieldConfig with the `components` above. So I created this class, but I'm not sure how to make it work properly and how to *plug* it into the framework / cms.

```
<?php

class CustomGridConfig extends ??? {

function __construct() {

    $config = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
      new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
      new GridFieldAddNewButton('toolbar-header-right'),
      new GridFieldTitleHeader()
      ... etc
    );

    return $config;

  }

}
```

Eventually it would be implemented in a `GridField` as follows:

```
GridField::create('Foo', 'Bar', $this->Foo(), new CustomGridConfig());
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to create a class within a class like that, also I'm not quite sure how to get this class loaded into the CMS.

Is the concept of this setup viable? If so, how? This would help me understand how to properly extend the framework / cms.

Comment: I'd suggest Dans or Jannes solution, maybe more Dans as it includes more documentation links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SilverStripe already comes with a set of `GridFieldConfig`s out of the box, that may already do what you need.

To answer your question you'd extend `GridFieldConfig` and do add your components in the constructor like this:

```
class CustomGridConfig extends GridFieldConfig {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->addComponents(
            new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
            new GridFieldAddNewButton('toolbar-header-right'),
            new GridFieldTitleHeader()
            ... etc
        );
    }
}
```

This class will become available to use after you perform a "flush" (appending `?flush` to any site URL) - see [the documentation on caching](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/performance/caching/#cleaning-caches-on-flush-1-requests).

See [the docs for information on the built in configs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/forms/field_types/gridfield/#bundled-gridfieldconfig).

Comment: I was wondering where I saw these default settings earlier. Great to see they are in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create custom `GridFieldConfig`s by extending `GridFieldConfig` like so:

```php
class CustomGridFieldConfig extends GridFieldConfig {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addComponent(new GridFieldToolbarHeader());
        $this->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewButton('toolbar-header-right'));
        // etc...
    }

}
```

And then pass it to your `GridField` like so:

```
GridField::create(
    'Foo', 
    'Bar', 
    $this->Foo(), 
    CustomGridFieldConfig::create()
);
```

Check out the class `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor` in file `GridFieldConfig.php` for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

your concept is good and setup is viable.  I'd have just a plain class and then add your method... should be fine as a constructor but if not a static method should be fine...

```
class CustomGridConfig {
    public static function create() {
        $config = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
              GridFieldToolbarHeader::create(),
              GridFieldAddNewButton::create('toolbar-header-right'),
              GridFieldTitleHeader::create()
              ... etc
            );

        return $config;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little strange approach to extending the GridFieldConfig because you lose any advantage of extending and effectively are just creating a factory class rather than a new GridFieldConfig. This also loses the benefit of the core because `Object` is no longer in the inheritance tree.

Comment: @DanHensby it isn't an extension of gridfield that is the point... it is a utility class to add those default configs to a GridField.  I considered saying extend it... but thought that wasn't what OP was asking.  I could be wrong :)

Comment: Correct Barry, I'm actually using it as merely a utility class. However Dan's solution might be more convenient in the future if any properties from parent class would be required.